The specified module was not found. Error loading "D:\Python\cuda_hello2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll"
I started a project. In the terminal I ran:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
In the file I wrote:
import torch
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
print(device)

Response:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\bbb\111.py", line 1, in 
import torch
File "D:\Python\bbb.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch_init_.py", line 148, in 
raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "D:\Python\bbb.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
Help me figure it out. I'm still learning.

This question is similar to: FBGEMM load error trying to use PyTorch on Windows. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
